# scala maxBy issue on list

Tags: scala

```
val dna1 = "ATATCCG"
val dna2 = "TCCGA"
val dna3 = "ATGTACTG"
val arr = Array.ofDim[(Int, (Int, Int, Int))](dna1.length + 1, dna2.length + 1, dna3.length + 1)

for (i1 <- 0 to dna1.length)
  for (i2 <- 0 to dna2.length)
    for (i3 <- 0 to dna3.length)
      arr(i1)(i2)(i3) = {
        def mkPair(i1: Int, i2: Int, i3: Int, diff: Int = 0) = {
          (arr(i1)(i2)(i3)._1 + diff, (i1, i2, i3))
        }
        if (i1 + i2 + i3 == 0) (0, null)
        else if (i1 * i2 * i3 == 0) (0, (0 max (i1 - 1), 0 max (i2 - 1), 0 max (i3 - 1)))
        else List(
          mkPair(i1 - 1, i2 - 1, i3 - 1, if (dna1(i1 - 1) == dna2(i2 - 1) && dna1(i1 - 1) == dna3(i3 - 1)) 1 else 0),
          mkPair(i1, i2 - 1, i3 - 1),
          mkPair(i1 - 1, i2, i3 - 1),
          mkPair(i1 - 1, i2 - 1, i3),
          mkPair(i1 - 1, i2, i3),
          mkPair(i1, i2 - 1, i3),
          mkPair(i1, i2, i3 - 1)
        ).maxBy(_._1)
      }
```

I am getting some error I do not still get about semicolon, where it shouldn't go?...

```
error: value maxBy is not a member of List[(Int, (Int, Int, Int))]
possible cause: maybe a semicolon is missing before `value maxBy'?
               ).maxBy(_._1)
                 ^
```

What would be the best way to overcome this issue with

Comment: As a side note you can collapse your code into a single `for(i1 <- 0 to dna1.length; i2 <- dna2.length; i3 <- dna3.length)`. Also you should be able to simply use `max`, as there is an implicit lexicographical ordering on tuples whose elements are ordered such that `(2, 1) > (1, 2)`.

Comment: could you please complete code, Would that be something like `for(i1 <- 0 to dna1.length; i2 <- dna2.length; i3 <- dna3.length)   def mkPair(i1: Int, i2: Int, i3: Int, diff: Int = 0) = {
          (arr(i1)(i2)(i3)._1 + diff, (i1, i2, i3))
        }` do not get the max part...

Comment: Using multiple generators in a single `for`-comprehension is equivalent to nesting each generator in its own comprehension; `for(a <- as; b <- bs) { ... }` is rewritten as `as.foreach(a => bs.foreach(b => ...))`, so you can eliminate two levels of indentation. As for `max`, try entering `List((1, 2), (2, 1)).max` in the repl - you will get `(2, 1)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compiles fine for me with scalac 2.10.0.   `maxBy` was added in Scala 2.9.0.  Make sure you are using scalac 2.9.0+ to compile your code.